# SaxParser and Wikipedia dump (10GB+)

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, sax, 32-bit, saxparser

I read that SaxParser is good for big files. But as we can see in documentation, methods of `ContentParser` class are using `32-bit` data types for storing position in file. Wikipedia dump can be file a lot bigger than `2GB`. Therefore, is this safe to use `SaxParser` with Wikipedia Dumps? If not - what should I use?

Comment: Is the wikipedia dump actually one big XML file? If not, then SAX will be fine.